# Error in plotting dose-response curve in ggplot with drc package

Tags: r, ggplot2, drc

I'm getting a half plotted graph when trying to plot the dose-response curve using ggplot in drc package. I'm trying to follow procedure given in a suplementary information from a [recent paper](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0146021) on dose response curve.
Here is my raw data

[image: raw data]

Please help me to find solution, thanks!

```
# Fit a log-logistic model with lower and upper asymptotic limits fixed at respectively 0 and 100

mod.Pyr <- drm(gi ~ conc, data = my_data, fct = LL.4(fixed = c(NA, 0, 100, NA)))

# new dose levels as support for the line

newdata <- expand.grid(conc=exp(seq(log(0.5), log(3000), length=1000)))

# predictions and confidence intervals

pm <- predict(mod.Pyr, newdata=newdata, interval="confidence")

# new data with predictions

newdata$p <- pm[,1]
newdata$pmin <- pm[,2]
newdata$pmax <- pm[,3]

# need to shift conc == 0 a bit up, otherwise there are problems with coord_trans

my_data$conc0 <- my_data$conc
my_data$conc0[my_data$conc0 == 0] <- 0.5

# plotting the curve

ggplot(my_data, aes(x = conc0, y = gi)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_ribbon(data=newdata, aes(x=conc, y=p, ymin=pmin, ymax=pmax), alpha=0.2) +
  geom_line(data=newdata, aes(x=conc, y=p)) +
  coord_trans(x="log") +
  xlab("Concentration (mg/l)") + ylab("Growth inhibition")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `conc` values above `log(3000)` and you only created `newdata` for values until `log(100)` so you're not able to fit until `log(3000)`, you just need to increase `log(100)` in expand.grid to higher values, examples with `log(3000)` :

```
newdata <- expand.grid(conc=exp(seq(log(0.5), log(3000), length=100)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. I wonder if it could be possible to include a couple of more data points on the x-axis before 1000, like 10 and 100 so that the graph is more readable. Also if it could be possible to squeeze the graph towards y-axis since the first concentration is 100 mg/l, a lot of space is taken up before this and i need to include seven graphs side by side. Please let me know if this is possible. Thanks again!